# How to Change Source_ID value after storing new contact in local dbl?

Tags: android, android-contacts

i want to store contacts on sql lite db. The problem was i am unable to identify the new contacts which are created.

**Solution for this**
I am using source_id to identify this newly added contact. Now the newly created contact source_id is null, here i can identify this.
**Problem now:** But how can i change this value when it is added in sql lite?

Comment: You are adding in native contact or your app SQLite database..?

Comment: The new contact will be created in phone to identify this contact i am using source_id of raw contacts table. Which when a contact is added is null by default. The problem is after storing this specific new contact the source id is still null. How this source id will be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not touch the `source_id` value, it is used by the sync-adapter that synced that contact to your phone, and you might be corrupting the contacts DB by modifying it.

Instead, you can use the [`Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP):

1. You query for all contacts that have `CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP` greater then the last time your app ran (that means they were either created or updated since you last updated your local SQLite DB)
2. Go over the list one-by-one, and see if their contact `_ID` is already in your DB or not, if it's not, it means this is a new contact - add it.